# I cannot launch Terminal after I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I am a new Ubuntu user. I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.10. Everything was fine until today when I opened my laptop. I cannot launch Terminal. I have tried 2 ways: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and Supper>Gnome-terminal... but they did not work.

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: you  can use virtual terminal

Comment: How can I use it, Debian !?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: Hello David. I did not know about that yet. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: My question here is that I cannot launch the Gnome-Terminal after I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10. Can you help me fix this!?

Comment: @NgaDo You should [edit] your question to narrow it down. This time, I’ve [done it](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1035994/4) for you. After you solve your problem with the terminal, don’t hesitate to [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) about your wifi problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, and I solved it by re-installing gnome-terminal via TTY.

Steps :

1. Open TTY1 shell by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1.
2. Login with your credentials.
3. Type `sudo apt purge gnome-terminal` to remove existing installation, if exists.
4. Reinstall Gnome-terminal by `sudo apt install gnome-terminal`.
5. Exit TTY1 by pressing CTRL+ALT+F7.

*If TTY1 is not accessible for any reason, try TTY2 and so on.*